# estimating mutual information via nearest neighbourhood

Tags: information-theory

I am not sure this is the best place to ask this kind of question about discussing the content of a paper. Anyway, here is my question:

There is a famous paper from Physical Review E 69, 066138(2004) called "Estimating Mutual Information" (http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0305641.pdf).

My question is why the author use the maximum norm(instead the $L_2$ norm) for combining $X$ and $Y$?

I think most people will have this question if they have ever read this paper. Thank you!

Comment: I guess it's because the set $\{(x,y):\|(x,y\|\le r\}$ has product structure only if $\|\cdot\|$ is the maximal norm. Their remark on page 5 seems to point in this direction. I guess their computations on that page would be substantially more involved if $L^2$ norm was used.

Comment: Thank you so much! True, under eq(26) on page 5, the author mentioned "the maximum norm is needed for some reason". I am interested in whether I could change(and modify) it into $L_2$ norm, or at least for his $I^{(1)}$ if $I^{(2)}$ cannot be changed. Because we usually apply Euclidean distance for the data. I will think about this. Thank you again for your help!